# Python - Translating best fit line in log plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, linear-regression

I'm trying a best fit linear regression line for huge arrays in a loglog plot.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

x = subhalos['SubhaloVmax']
y = subhalos['SubhaloMass'] * 1e10 / 0.704 # in units of M_sol h^-1
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, slope_std_error = stats.linregress(np.log(x), np.log(y))

predict_y = intercept + slope * x
pred_error = y - predict_y
degrees_of_freedom = len(x) - 2
residual_std_error = np.sqrt(np.sum(pred_error**2) / degrees_of_freedom)

idx = np.argsort(x) 

plt.plot(x,y,'k.')
plt.plot(x[idx], predict_y[idx], 'b--')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('$V_{max}$ [km s$^{-1}$]')
plt.ylabel('$M_{sub} $ [$M_\odot h^{-1}$]')
plt.title(' $V_{max} - M_{sub}$ relation ')
```

giving me this graph

[image]

I would've thought that my code would set up the y intercept automatically. But that does not seem to be the case.

How do I translate the line to the correct intercept?

Comment: Actually, you [should not fit a linear function to the logarithm](http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html).

Comment: What would be more appropriate to fit then?

Comment: I think @MoritzLotze's statement is too general. If you have a theoretical model that suggests a functional form, use that. If it happens to be linear, no problem. The advice in the link comes in handy when you don't _have_ a theoretical model and you're doing "exploratory fitting" to determine what form a model might take. In that case, be aware of the limitations of your fitting procedure. Just because a linear fit seems to work doesn't mean the trend is actually linear. But that's out of scope for this site. You could find more information on [stats.SE], [physics.SE], or [scicomp.SE].

Answer (score 0):

You're computing the regression on `log(x)` vs `log(y)`, so your prediction should actually be computed as

```
predict_logy = intercept + slope * logx
```

Whether you would then compute the residuals as `log(y) - predict_logy` or `y - exp(predict_logy)` or something else depends on your application.

Comment: @ David Z, I followed your advice, this only changed the slope of my line unfortunately.

Comment: There's something else you're not doing correctly, then, but I can't tell you what (and I doubt anyone else can either) without having more specific information.

Comment: Would it make things easier to just plot my values in log on the regular x-y axis?

Comment: You could do that, but I don't think it would really make the plotting any _easier_. It's just a different way to accomplish nearly the same thing.